# Moment.js shows 00/Fr/2021

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs, date-format, date-formatting

I am trying to change the format of the date using below React function below.

The date that I am passing is 2021-12-31

My function is like below

```
export const getDate = (date) => {
    if (date?.length > 0) {
     moment(date);
    }
    return moment(date).format('mm/dd/yyyy');
};
```

Two issues:

1. Control never goes inside if, even though the length of the date is > 0.
2. When I print `return moment(date).format('mm/dd/yyyy');` it gives value as `00/Fr/2021`

Comment: isn't `mm` minutes in moment?

Comment: Ohh ok, but then how can I get month date and year

Comment: also, control never goes inside if, even hough length is greater than 0

Comment: should be DD not dd

Comment: Thought you'd have figured that out ... MM/DD/YYYY

Comment: how do you know `moment(date);` never gets executed in the `if`? you ignore the result completely. That `if` code is completely pointless

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong string to format. Like explained in the comments, `mm` is for minutes en `dd` is for day in a word. You should use `MM` instead of `mm` to get the month and `DD` instead of `dd` to get the day as a number.

Here is the documentation where you can find this:
https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

In the future it's good to read documentation thoroughly when you get stuck ;-)

Comment: also YYYY ... seems OP needs it fully explained

Comment: Ok, that helped!

Comment: But still I have one issue, the control is never going into if condition, I want to format date only if the length is greater than 0

Comment: isn't the year case insensitive? @JaromandaX

Comment: what is being passed into the method?

Comment: 2021-12-31 this is being passed

Comment: @LarsVonk - may well be in a later version, but the version of momentjs I've used, `yyyy` comes out as `yyyy` :p

Comment: @PurvaParulekar - the `if` code effectively does nothing since you "throw away" the result of calling `moment(date);` ... or `2021-12-31` is `1978` ... or are you passing a string? either way, the if code is meaningless and doesn't actually do anything useful

Comment: ohhh yes! You are right

Comment: I now get it, I never used return in my if condition @JaromandaX

Comment: Now it works fine

Comment: @JaromandaX while it does work with lowercase `yyyy` I do think what you are suggesting is a better option since everything uppercase just looks better and it will work in older versions as well then.